# Trying to add a new record to a table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

Hey guys i've been trying to work this out but i'm trying to add a new user to a student table and i keep getting the error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Here is my code, I think it has something to do with the dob variable. I'm using visual studio 2010.

```
    SqlConnection insertStu = new SqlConnection(ConString());

    insertStu.Open();

    string dataStu = "INSERT INTO [Student] ([fName], [lName], [dob], [gender], [address],
    [suburb], [postcode], [username], [parentName], [parentContact]) VALUES (@fName, @lName,
    @dob,    @gender, @address, @suburb, @postcode, @username, @parentName, @parentContact)";

    SqlCommand insertStuData = new SqlCommand(dataStu, insertStu);

    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", given.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", surname.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", suburb.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcode.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", given.Text + surname.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentName", pname.Text);
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentContact", phone.Text);
    insertStuData.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
```

---

Thanks for the help guys I fixed it using the following

```
DateTime bday = Convert.ToDateTime(dob.Text);
```

and in the variable collecting i did the following

```
insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", bday);
```

Is that ideal, should I have done anything else?

Comment: It's expecting you to pass a `DateTime` object instead of a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dob.Text);
```

may have caused the issue, make sure dob.Text is DateTime type
without knowing your table structure, I am just guessing

Comment: you should try DateTime dt = new DateTime(1980,1,1); and replace dob.Text with dt

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are using a string where a date it required. Use the following, with proper exception hadling of course.

```
insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", surname.Text);
/* New Code */
DateTime birthDate = new DateTime();
if(DateTime.TryParse(dob.Text, out birthDate ))    
{
    insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", birthDate);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Date incorectly formatted");
    /*Or However you want to handle the incorectly formatted date*/
}
/* End New Code*/
insertStuData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender.Text);
```

If you absolutely 100% know that the date is going to be correctly formatted, you can use `DateTime.Parse` instead without the need for the additional variable and `if..else..` statement.